# Neodynamic Barcode Professional for SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, neodynamic

Our application needs to be able to render barcodes to PDF documents that will be accessible over the internet.  Our technology stack includes SQL Server Reporting Services so we would like to leverage it and its ability to render to PDF; however, we are not able to get it to embed the `FREE3OF9.ttf` barcode font in any consistent manner.

I have reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437/custom-font-in-sql-server-2005-reporting-services), but would like to know any if any one has used Neodynamic products, particularly their SSRS product and whether or not they were satisfied with it.  If anyone has any other solutions besides Neodynamic for rendering barcodes to a PDF via SSRS I would also like to hear those.

Comment: @SébastienSevrin: has someone already mentioned that code formatting for proper nouns isn't appropriate? Inline code formatting is fine for code and text that can be considered I/O (console output, URLs, data, etc).

Comment: @halfer: Thanks for the info, you are the first one telling me that. I thought that doing it for keywords was easier to read. Do you know if quoting error messages is appropriate or do they have to be formatted differently? Is there a topic on this on the meta? Thanks.

Comment: @Sébastien: [there's this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261262/472495) and likely to be several others. Not sure if "all the guidelines" are gathered on one page - it's something I absorbed bit by bit, I think. I think I spotted a reference to your edit in a Meta post yesterday, but can't find it now.

Comment: @halfer: ok thanks, I found [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286706/how-should-compiler-errors-linker-errors-and-logs-be-formatted) also for error messages, but nobody agreed on a way to go, I think a unique formatting rule page with samples would be great for starters. Anyway let's close this off-topic subject, I'll raise this later on Meta.

Comment: @Sébastien: error messages are fine as a quote block. Literally, a quote is "something said/written by somebody/something else". An error can be regarded as the "voice of the computer", so a quote device seems very natural indeed. Some people use code formatting (because an error is also console I/O) and I think that's OK.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used SRSS before, but I have written barcode generating software. If you are looking for alternatives, writing your own is not too difficult.

You can find all of the information regarding barcode encoding online. I used [Code 128](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128), and simply created a table of values in my source code. Rendering the barcode is just a matter of drawing solid black and white bars based on the information in the table, so you don't need to worry about embedding fonts.

It looks like you want to use Reporting Services, so maybe this doesn't help. Either way, good luck with it!

Answer (score 0):

I use it at work and like it, it is very easy to use and has many different bar code options. I recently created a bar code our of an image outline, it was pretty cool. The Tool is easy to use its pretty much like adding an image to the report, you choose which field to populate the bar code, choose the bar code style and boom you're done.