# Font issue while rendering SSRS Reports

Tags: reporting-services, fonts, msbi

I need my report to be in "HiraginoKaku" font while exporting to PDF. I don't have this font installed on my SSRS. So i am trying to achieve it with this expression =IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="PDF","HiraginoKaku","Arial") but no luck.

I tried this also =IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="EXCELOPENXML","Arial","HiraginoKaku") still no luck.

I have used Arial as default while creating report.
Please help me how to get this font thing done.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be having a similar issue found in this question below:

[Custom font in SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437/custom-font-in-sql-server-2005-reporting-services)

Have you tried this?

Comment: No, i can't install fonts. I don't have rights. Need a work around.

Answer (score 0):

1.you need to download some fonts to download  like TAT files 
2.after that put the file in c://windows/fonts
3.now restart your system and check